# why does this compile without any unchecked type warnings?

Tags: java, generics

Why does the following code compile cleanly without any warnings, even with `xlint:all` ?

```
class A<V> {

    public V v;

    public <V> A() {
    }

    public static <V> A<V> create() {
        return new A<V>();
    }
}


public class FooMain {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        A.create().v = 5;
        A.create().v = "a string";
    }
}
```

running:

```
javac -Xlint:all src/FooMain.java
```

results in a clean compile without any warnings (unchecked, etc.). What is the type parametrization of the instance of the generic class `A` that gets's created on the first line and what on the second? And how does the compiler determine the type? By looking at the type of the r-values?

Comment: From my naive understanding: No type can be inferred so it defaults to A<Object>...

Comment: That would be my initial thought as well...

Comment: I vote to keep it open as this is not opinion based. The accepted answer is not an opinion but a good explanation of how the whole issue works, for real.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both of the statements, the compiler does not have enough information to infer the type argument for `V`. When this happens, it defaults to `V`'s upper bound, which is `Object`.

The assignments are valid because both `5` and `"a string"` are assignable to `Object`.

We can show that the type of `A.create().v` is `Object` by trying to assign it to a more specific type:

```
Integer i = A.create().v; // Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to Integer
```

The error is the same, even if we assign a more specific type first (the result of an assignment expression is the type of the assigned variable):

```
Integer i = (A.create().v = 5); // same error
```

---

Note that a "type witness" can be used to explicitly specify generic type arguments, in the case that they aren't inferred:

```
Integer i = A.<Integer>create().v; // valid

A.<String>create().v = 5;           // incompatible types
A.<Integer>create().v = "a string"; //
```

These are contrived examples just to demonstrate compiler behavior, but a type witness is occasionally useful, [for example](http://ideone.com/3eWceB):

```
static void m(List<String> list) { }

public static void main(String args[]) {

    m(Collections.emptyList());         // error
    m(Collections.<String>emptyList()); // valid
}
```

Comment: Ok so it appears there's two schools of thought here. I'll revisit the accepted answer in the coming days...

Comment: The second code block is good enough for me. If @MarcusJuniusBrutus will unaccept my answer, I'll delete it.

Comment: OK, so we've established that the Java compiler cannot infer generic parametrization from RHS types ? Or am I stating it too broadly?

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus I would hesitate to be so broad - there can be an arbitrary amount of nesting and dereferencing within either side of an assignment operator. I think it's problematic to look at it in terms of LHS or RHS. More accurately, the compiler has a number of ingredients available for inference of a generic method's type arguments: the arguments, and the "target type" (which is the LHS of an assignment up until Java 8, where it's generalized to allow calls like `m(Collections.emptyList())` in my last example). In your example, `A.create()` has neither arguments nor target type.

Answer (score 1):

Due to these two statement

```
A.create().v = 5;
A.create().v = "a string";
```

Compiler will easily resolve in the first case `<V>` by `<Integer>`

and in the second case `<V>` by `<String>`

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes. This answer isn't very well-written, but it is correct.

Comment: I didn't, thus the comment; I upvoted because it's essentially correct.

Comment: I downvoted this answer for the same reasoning as for chrylis's answer - see the comments under it.

Comment: People can downvote answers that does not fulfill OP's question or that shows misleading information for future readers. And your answer misleads readers =\. If you don't believe me, refer to [@PaulBellora's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21563687/1065197)